# JavaScript Zoom whole Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

I'm searching for a JQuery script that can zoom in a whole div. I found the following plugins:

http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/#
and
http://www.albanx.com/?pid=1&subid=13

The plugins have exactly the things I need (just zoom in and out with your scrollwheel). But I have a problem, I need to have a script that zoom in a complete Div. Can someone help me please?

Comment: what do you mean by zooming a complete div? A div is just a container tag

Comment: Yes, I mean all the content in a div. I am going to place a imagemap inside the div, with a landscape with different buildings on it. And sometimes there are animating gifs on the landscape. When an user zoom in, all the images should zoom in (zo the whole div).

Comment: I don't think you can zoom on normal (specially dynamic) content I think it only works with images. Only solution it would be to draw everything on a canvas and then you have more freedom, but it would be quite complex.

Comment: Canvas offers a solution, but not the only solution. CSS3's scale transform allows one to zoom irrespective of the content.

Answer (score 2):

what about using the CSS3 transform 'scale' operation -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform? you'll have to write up the javascript for dealing with the mousewheel, but this will work (I've done this before).

Seems like there's decent support, too: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d (note from caniuse: The scale transform can be emulated in IE < 9 using Microsoft's "zoom" extension, others are (not easily) possible using the MS Matrix filter)

Answer (score 0):

A code example (jsfiddle or something) would probably be pretty helpful to get a better idea of what you want to achieve. Generally I reckon the CSS property "zoom" animated with jQuery might help here ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ddZx/9/)), but this only works in chrome/safari atm.